# Form file of netbeans project has been changed

Tags: java, netbeans

I dont know how the form file of netbeans project has been changed.Even I didn't open the src folder. Now opening the design of form is showing an error message "The Form file format is not recognised" . But my project is still running and it shows every form at run time. But I have to make some changes in form Design. How can i do ?Opening Form design is showing error  message. Please Answer it. Your help will be apprecated.

Comment: At runtime, form files aren't used. Only the Java code matters. Maybe you have changed your version of NetBeans. Try to find a previous version of the file in your version control system (you have one, right?). Or edit the Java code by hand. Or start from scratch. One more reason to avoid the NetBeans GUI editor.

Comment: Version of netbeans is same as previous one."Start from scratch" means ? Dont i reget that form file any how ? Is there any other method to design our form without having form file ?

Comment: "Start from scratch" means deleting the previous Java and form files and recreate them from the start. The form file is used by Netbeans because Netbeans can't figure out what the form looks like from the Java code. All the parts of the Java code surrounded with comments like "auto-generated by Netbeans" (I don't remember the exact wording) are generated thanks to the form file.

Comment: @ JB Nizet that is i dont have any other solution except recreating my  project ??

Comment: Not your project. Just this specific class. And only if you want to keep using the Netbeans GUI editor. And only if you don't have a version control system keeping the history of all the files in your project, like SVN or Git. This is one of the numerous problems that such tools allow avoiding. Use a VCS.

Comment: @JBNizet Are you talking about CVS ? I dont know how to use CVS tool. Whenever I open CVS menu, I find only one submenu active in it that is "Checkout" and it asks for CVS root and password.

Comment: CVS is ooooold and obsolete. It shouldn't be used anymore. Use SVN or Git, for example. And these tools need to be learnt and installed. You can't just click on a button without even understanding you're doing.